# how to reset hidden text fields when a form is duplicated

Tags: javascript, forms, duplicates, reset

I have a form with dropdown select menus, and depending what you choose, it will show a hidden text fields that you have to full fill. When I click on the 'duplicate button', the javascript works fine and duplicates the entire form. The select dropdown menu and all the fields that are NOT hidden are reset, which is what I want. However, all the hidden fields end up duplicating the answers from the previous form.

The 2nd problem is, if I don't select a choice that does NOT contain a hidden field in my original form, on the duplicate form, the javascript to show the hidden fields for the dropdown menus will not work. For example, there's a dropdown with choices 1 and 2. If you choose 1, there's no hidden field that shows, and if you choose 2, there will be a hidden field that you have to answer. If I chose #1 in the previous form, then in the duplicate form, the dropdown shows both 1 and 2, but nothing will happen if I choose 2, and that's because in the previous form I had chosen #1 so I guess the javascript function didn't get duplicated? what if on the duplicate form I want to choose #2? I can't.

Here's my code

---

**HTML**

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <select class="selectDD" id="FHB_OrgEvent" onchange='showIfEvent();'>
            <option value="1" >1</option>
            <option value="2" >2</option>
        </select>

    <div style="display:none;" class="hidden" id="showFhbEventName">
        <input type="text" id="FHBEventName" placeholder="Name of Event"/>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;" class="hidden" id="showFhbEventDesc">
        <input type="text" id="FHBEventDesc" placeholder="Please provide a brief description of the event or activity"/>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="add-del-buttons" class="add-del-buttons">
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="duplicate">
</div>
```

---

**Javascript for showing hidden fields**

```
function showIfEvent() {
    if (FHB_OrgEvent.value == "1") {
        showFhbEventName.style.display = "block";
        showFHBEventDesc.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        showFhbEventName.style.display = "none";
        showFHBEventDesc.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

---

**Javascript for Duplicate function**

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

    // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
    newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

});
```